# Slider with vertical parallax effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, parallax

I've created a simple slider for my client to be able to update using [Flexslider](https://github.com/woothemes/FlexSlider), and elsewhere on their site they have a vertical scrolling parallax effect. Now they want a slider with vertical scrolling parallax effects...

[Here's an example of the desired effect](http://www.kriesi.at/themes/enfold/homepage/transparent-header/)

For my parallax effect I used [Parallax.js](http://pixelcog.github.io/parallax.js/), which was great when I only needed a single image to have the effect, but not much use now I need the slider to have it.

The above example uses [Avia Slider](http://aviathemes.com/aviaslider/), but the parallax effect appears to be done by something else (as Avia doesn't have any such effect that I can see).

How can I create a simple parallax effect for my existing Flexslider slider (or any other slider)? It seems like it should be a simple effect that doesn't necessarily need a jQuery plugin.

Comment: What have you tried? With near 20K rep you should know that you need to demonstrate effort  and show us where you're stuck.

Comment: @j08691 I answered my own question ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I solved it:

I added `transform: translate3d(0,0,0)` to the slider element, and then modified it as the user scrolls down (eg. `transform: translate3d(0,10px,0)`). A simple, clean solution:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if($(window).scrollTop() > 0) {

        var parallaxDistance = ($(window).scrollTop()/2), 
            parallaxCSS = "translate3d(0, "+ parallaxDistance +"px , 0)";

        $('.slides').css('transform', parallaxCSS);

    } else {

        $('.slides').css('transform', 'translate3d(0, 0, 0)');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to just place the element absolute. The effective distance the parallax effect should take place has to be in the `overflow: hidden` area. Which means, if you want a completely fixed background the width of this picture has to be `width: 100vw`.

Then all you have to do is trigger a scroll event and transform your picture using `translateX()` or by changing the position of the `background-image` and multiply the value with the actual speed.
Since the scroll event triggers really often and the browser won't rerender every time you could use `requestAnimationFrame()`.

```
var translate = function() {
    $('#object').css('transform','translateX('+($(window).scrollTop()*.4)+'px)');
}

$(window).on('scroll', function() {
   window.requestAnimationFrame(translate);
});
```

Here a little prototype, so you have a better idea.

```js
$(document).on('ready', function(){
  var $outerWrapper = $('#outerWrapper');
  var $innerWrapper = $('#innerWrapper');
  var $innerWrapperWidth = $innerWrapper.outerWidth();
  var $slides = $('.slide');
  var slideWidth = $slides.eq(0).outerWidth();
  var effective = slideWidth * 0.5;

  $outerWrapper.on('scroll', function(e){
    for (var i = 0; i < $slides.length; i++) {
      $element = $slides.eq(i);
      var s = $element.offset().left;
      if (s < slideWidth && s > 0) {
        var percent = s/slideWidth;
        var translate = effective * percent;
        if ($element.hasClass('parallax')){
          $element.css('background-position', '-' + translate +'px 0');
        }
      }
    }
   
  });
});
```

```css
.slide{
  width: 298px;
  height: 148px;
  background-color: #dadada;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  float: left;
  background-image: url('http://www.technocrazed.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/Landscape-wallpaper-7.jpg');
  background-size: 100%;
}

.slide.parallax{
  background-size: 150%;
}

#innerWrapper{
  width: 1500px;
  height: 150px;
}

#outerWrapper{
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="outerWrapper">
  <div id="innerWrapper">
    <div class="slide"></div>
    <div class="slide parallax"></div>
    <div class="slide"></div>
    <div class="slide parallax"></div>
    <div class="slide"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your snippet seems to do something completely different to your first answer?